# iOS Charts: Top axis line not drawn when labels at bottom

Tags: ios-charts

I'm using a LineChart with the x axis labels at the bottom and I don't understand why the top x axis line isn't drawn. xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled is set to true.

Is it possible to have the top axis line drawn without labels at the top of the chart?

[Image of charts with and without top x axis line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrJTP.png)

Comment: What you want here ? XAxis need to show on top or something else ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to have the x axis line drawn on top even when there are no axis labels on top. I've replaced the image in my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your requirement, you need to enable Graph border by enabling the below property

```
lineChartView.drawBordersEnabled = true
```

Hope this will help to show you the top line for `XAxis`.

**Sample:**

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what is was looking for. Thanks!